# app engine with cloud storage local server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have an application in appengine that access google cloud storage.
I'm using java.
I'm not using google-gcs-client because I have incompatibility with this library.

Follow how I'm using my code:

```
    final Builder builder = new Storage.Builder(Utils.getDefaultTransport(), Utils.getDefaultJsonFactory(), GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault());
storage =  builder.setApplicationName(applicationName).build();

final Bucket newBucket = new Bucket();
newBucket.setName(bucket);
storage.buckets().insert(myProjectId, newBucket).execute();
```

When I deploy my app, it's ok, because he application use default account server transfer the file to GCS and the app works fine.

I would like simulate this transfer in local server (localhost).
I read others questions here, but they were in others context, maybe you know help me :)

I tried download a .json file account service e use de variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with this account. but, does not work

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Caller does not have storage.buckets.get access to bucket mybucket.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Caller does not have storage.buckets.get access to bucket mybucket."
}
```

How I'll simulate de cloud storage locally?